# How to use repmgr with PostgreSQL 10?

Tags: postgresql, repmgr

Followed the official [repmgr document](https://repmgr.org/docs/4.2/quickstart-postgresql-configuration.html), I set these items to the configuration file:

```
  shared_preload_libraries = 'repmgr'
  max_wal_senders = 10
  max_replication_slots = 10
  wal_level = 'hot_standby'
  hot_standby = on
  archive_mode = on
```

However, in the `/var/lib/pgsql/10/data/postgresql.conf` file, something default as

```
#wal_level = replica                    # minimal, replica, or logical
                                        # (change requires restart)
```

Doesn't have `hot_standby` option.

If I use the config as repmgr document, when I want to create a database or user, alwasy hanging.

```
createuser -s myuser
createdb -E UNICODE -l en_US.UTF-8 -T template0 mydb -O myuser
```

But use the default postgresql configuration will work well.

So how to use `repmgr` with PostgreSQL 10 correctly?

Comment: `hot_standby` is not a value for `wal_level` it's [a separate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-HOT-STANDBY) property (which needs to go on a line of its own)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Would you like to write it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repmgr doc you linked to says to use `wal_level = 'hot_standby'` with PG versions 9.5 or older, and `wal_level = 'replica'` for PG versions 9.6 or newer.

> ```
> # Ensure WAL files contain enough information to enable read-only queries
> # on the standby.
> #
> #  PostgreSQL 9.5 and earlier: one of 'hot_standby' or 'logical'
> #  PostgreSQL 9.6 and later: one of 'replica' or 'logical'
> #    ('hot_standby' will still be accepted as an alias for 'replica')
> #
> # See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-WAL-LEVEL
> ```

You're using PostgreSQL 10, so `replica` or `logical` should be used for this option.